# XDocument.Parse() and XDocument.Load() both null when file exists

Tags: c#, wix, linq-to-xml

I have this code:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(webConfigPath))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    webConfig = sr.ReadToEnd();

XDocument web = XDocument.Parse(webConfig);
```

I also tried

```
XDocument web = XDocument.Load(webConfigPath);
```

For some reason, my XDocument is always null. The file exists and, in the first example, `webconfig` contains the contents of the document but my XDocument is still always null. Can anyone help me make sense of this? This may be irrelevant but the code is running during a WIX custom action. No exceptions are thrown until I attempt to use the XDocument later.

Comment: can you post a reproducable example or at least tell us what the `webConfigPath` is ?

Comment: @Selman22 I'll try to make a postable solution that will reproduce the problem. The path is `C:\Program Files\My Company\Web\Web.config`

Comment: @sirdank Strange... I tried with a default generated web.config and is working with your code

Comment: @vvv Well thanks for trying! I've been trying to reproduce this with a smaller code base and have been unsuccessful.